# Passing parameters in url using python scripting

Tags: python, python-2.7

My need : i want to pass a payload in each parameter and get the result stored in text file. i want to know how to pass the payload for all parameters in a URL using python

FYI : i am pulling url from text file and also writing output to text file.

Need to pass parameter in between = &

Ex url : http://apps.hello.com/appeditprofile/appeditprofileupdate.php&MARITAL_STATUS=1&ENCID=d961e7e192042c955bde7b68e38c25a72&TOFEET=5-8&FROMFEET=4-5&

Comment: Your example URL is not a valid URL; however ignoring that part - the URL you are reading from the file, does it already have a lot of `&=` attached to it?

Comment: yeah!!! i have lot of =& .... I need to pass parameters in between =& @Burhan Khalid

Answer (score 0):

You can add (Concatenate) variable by using plus (+) sign.

**Eg:**

```
 url = `http://example.com`
 var1 = test
 name = 'Arshid'
 payload = '?action='+var1+'&name='+var2
```

**Update:-**

Save text as following format in each line of (**textfile.txt**)

> {'var1' : '1','var2' : 'd961e7e192042c955bde7b68e38c25a72','var3' :
>    '5-8','var4' : '4-5'}
>
> {'var1' : '1','var2' :
>    'd961e7e192042c955bde7b68e38c25a72','var3' : '5-8','var4' : '4-5'}

```
for line in open('textfile.txt'):
        url = 'http://apps.hello.com/appeditprofile/appeditprofileupdate.php&MARITAL_STATUS='+line.get('var1')+'&ENCID='+line.get('var2')+'&TOFEET='+line.get('var3')+'&FROMFEET='+line.get('var4')
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to python programming could you please elaborate me with an example (plz use my url that i mentioned and explain)

Comment: Thanks!!!!! And i have a lot of url that i need to fetch from my text file and need to pass payloads to all the parameters in that links (FYI : the parameters will vary from url to url)

Comment: But i need to fetch payloads from a text file and i have some 100+ payloads. Need to pass each payload in a url for each parameter

Comment: You can fetch text from file by `for line in open("myfile.txt") :`

Comment: how can i pass after opening like above?

Comment: But the actual thing over here is i want to pass a payload in each parameter and get the result stored in text file and again pass the same payload to second parameter and get the result and so on.......

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend using `urllib` which will handle encodings for you as well.  Building off of Arshid’s example:

```
import urllib
url = 'http://example.com'
params = { 'var1': 'test', 'name': 'Arshid' }
url = '%s?%s' % (url, urllib.urlencode(params),)
```

You can see the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#examples) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is to read the URL correctly, and extract its *querystring*, which is the part with all the `&=`. Next, insert your key/value pair, then construct the original URL back:

```
>>> import urllib, urlparse
>>> original = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?a=b&c=d'
>>> new_values = {'key': 42}
>>> parts = urlparse.urlparse(original)
>>> original_qs = urlparse.parse_qs(parts.query)
>>> original_qs.update(new_values)
>>> new_qs = urllib.urlencode(original_qs, True)
>>> print(new_qs)
a=b&c=d&key=42
```

Comment: i want to fetch the url from text file and also i need to extract its qureystring for each url?

Comment: Yes, you will have to put that logic in a loop.

Comment: what is 42 in your code? May i know where to put that logic? And also please help with that logic - Burhan Khalid